# Overriding init method of Django model

Tags: python, django-models

What I am trying to do is implement a 'follower system' for my app and I just want to make sure a user can't be followed multiple times by the same user. I can't seem to implement this as the admin continues to let me create duplicate relationships.

models.py

```
     class FollowRelationshipManager(models.Manager):
        def create_followrelationship(self, follower, followee, date):
            if FollowRelationship.objects.filter(
                follower=follower,
                followee=followee
                ).exists():
                    raise ValueError('User is already followed')
            else:
                followrelationship = self.create(
                    follower=follower,
                    followee=followee,
                    date=date
                )
                return followrelationship
    
    
    class FollowRelationship(models.Model):
        follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follower', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        followee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='followee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make use of a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) which will prevent that the combination of the two (or more) fields:

```
class FollowRelationship(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='follower',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    followee = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='followee',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['follower', 'followee'],
                name='follow_once'
            )
        ]
```

This will also be enforced at the database level.

Prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
# prior to Django-2.2

class FollowRelationship(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='follower',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    followee = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='followee',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['follower', 'followee']]
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).